# Bounding the symmetric difference of a Borel set with a finite union of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

> For $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ a bounded Borel set. Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$  there exists a set $U$ which is a finite union of intervals such that $\lambda_1(A \triangle U)\leq \epsilon$ With $\triangle$ being the symmetric difference of $A$ and $U$

I'm currently in a measure theory class and I have this question and I just don't know where to start. I have a feeling I may need to use the definition of an outer measure, as well as the fact that the complement of an interval in the semi-algebra of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite union of intervals, but I'm not sure. I'm really struggling in this module in knowing how to approach questions so if anyone had any advice I'd really appreciate that.

Edit: $\lambda_1$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$
So for an interval $(a,b]$ we have that $\lambda_1((a,b])=b-a$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you recall how $\lambda_1$ is defined?

Comment: I've added that since I didn't define it, I've just looked again at my notes. It's the unique measure that agrees with the length function on $\mathbb{R}$, from the Carathéodory Extension Theorem? I still don't really see a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: (1) Use outer measure to approximate $A$, to within measure $\varepsilon/2$, by an open superset. (2) Recall that an open subset of $\mathbb R$ is the union of countably many disjoint intervals. The measure of the open set is the sum of the measures of those intervals. (3) Approximate that infinite sum, to within measure $\varepsilon/2$, by a finite partial sum.

Comment: Ah right thank you, that gives me $\lambda_1(A) = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \lambda_1(I_n) + \epsilon $ is that right?